# Devise update password route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

On a rails app setup with Devise, i am trying to provide users with a form to change passwords.

i have followed the solution 3 from the Devise wiki:https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

and accordingly have in a user controller

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update_password
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update(user_params)
      # Sign in the user by passing validation in case their password changed
      bypass_sign_in(@user)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "edit"
    end
   end
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users,
           path: "", path_names: {
             sign_in: "login",
             sign_out: "logout",
             sign_up: "register",
             edit: "settings"
           },
           controllers: {
             registrations: "users",
             sessions: "users/sessions"
           }
resources :users do
 patch 'update_password'    
end
```

Rake routes gives me :

```
user_update_password_path   POST    (/:locale)/users/:user_id/update_password(.:format)     

users#update_password {:locale=>/fr|en|de/}
```

the link to access the menu is the following:

```
<%= link_to user_update_password_path(current_user) %>
```

in browser, that links directs me to :

> http://localhost:3000/en/users/1/update_password

but I receive a Routing error

> No route matches [GET] "/en/users/1/update_password"

When I wrap the

```
resources :users do
  resources :wishlists
  collection do
    patch 'update_password'
  end
end
```

the link_to send to

> http://localhost:3000/1/password

Which results in the error

> undefined local variable or method `user_update_password_path' for
>
> ## <#:0x00007f86cfe48f10> Did you mean?  user_password_path

however, rails routes shows:

```
update_password_users PATCH  (/:locale)/users/update_password(.:format)                                               users#update_password {:locale=>/fr|en|de/}
```

but a link_to

> update_password_users_path

results in an error

> Could not find devise mapping for path "/en/users/update_password".
>   This may happen for two reasons:
>
> 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:
>
> devise_scope :user do
>       get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"   end
>
> 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.    If so,
>   you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:
>
> @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

What have I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the solution 3 it says `resource` not `resources`. Watch the differences carefully between yours and the below one  -

```
resource :user, only: [:edit] do
  collection do
    patch 'update_password'
  end
end
```

Second the like should direct to `edit_user_path` not `update_password_user` as that is the `patch` route.

Third, you have to add a `edit` action to your controller as the wiki suggests. And also a form for the action.

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end
```

and in `app/views/users/edit.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password" } ) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, "Password" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off"  %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="action_container">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You missed lots of things. Try reading the wiki again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

I missed the singular on resource but I had the controller update and the form in place.

Comment: however, I still have an issue with the link_to. it overrides the edit user form that is already in place (and from which I want to split out the change_password action).

i have tried to render to  "edit_password" instead of edit, and create the def dit_password with @user= current_user action.